# Prepare a file for inputing to mysql

Tags: mysql, bash

I have a file that is split into sections. Each section starts with a headerline e.g.:

```
Company,CountryA,-,-,-,-
then 1 to 20 lines of data with the following format
,,date,CompanyA,valueA1,valueA2
,,date,CompanyB,valueB1,valueB2
,,date,CompanyC,valueC1,valueC2
,,date,CompanyD,valueD1,valueD2
Company,CountryB,-,-,-,-
then more data
,,date,CompanyE,valueE1,valueE2
,,date,CompanyF,valueF1,valueF2
,,date,CompanyG,valueG1,valueG2
```

What I need to be able to do is convert this into a file with the following format.

```
Company,CountryA,-,-,-,-,,date,CompanyA,valueA1,valueA2
Company,CountryA,-,-,-,-,,date,CompanyB,valueB1,valueB2
Company,CountryA,-,-,-,-,,date,CompanyC,valueC1,valueC2
Company,CountryB,-,-,-,-,,date,CompanyD,valueD1,valueD2
Company,CountryB,-,-,-,-,,date,CompanyE,valueE1,valueE2
Company,CountryB,-,-,-,-,,date,CompanyF,valueF1,valueF2
Company,CountryB,-,-,-,-,,date,CompanyG,valueG1,valueG2
```

i.e. I need a script that will go through the file and read each line and if it finds a line starting company it saves it add adds it to the beginning of the subsequent line (if it begins ,,) until the line begins with Company again.

I am sure there is probably a simple way of doing this but it is beyond my simple scripting abilities.

Comment: SO is a Q/A site, not a free coding service. Pls demonstrate what you have tried to achive the required output, what error message or unexpected behaviour you encountered, and we will help you to fix it. But pls do not expect us to write a script for you from scratch.

Comment: Agree with @Shadow; but since I'm feeling benevolent - and just went thru something similar: in Windows Notepad, Edit - your from will be ,,date and your to will be Company,CountryA,-,-...,,date - Replace All - after splitting up the files to separate CountryA, CountryB, etc - you can stitch them back together at the end or do separate LOAD DATAs. Good luck.

Comment: Apologies for that. I really did not have anything near what I wanted to do, and which was not working, I have tried and not just come here expecting you to just do it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sed :

```
sed -n '/^Company/h;{/^,,/{G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1/p}}' file
```

Lines starting with `Company` are added to the hold space and subsequent lines starting with `,,` are prepend with the hold line.